# PHP POST request via AJAX returns source code

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send POST and retrieve data from that POST. Instead I get the source code of my AJAX script (`ajax.php`).

```
<?php
$params = array('action' => 'LOL');
$query = http_build_query($params);
$contextData = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'content' => $query
);

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => $contextData));
$result = file_get_contents(
    'ajax.php',
    false,
    $context
);

var_dump($result);
?>
```

What gives?

Comment: file get content is used to retrive the contents of the given file in string format.. so with this you will get all the code from ajax.php as a string in your file

Comment: `file_get_contents()` reads the file and prints its contents (source code in your case). Try using `require('ajax.php');` to evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

The typical use of ajax is to have a call from javascript (in the client browser), submit a request to the server. The server would then run some code (e.g. written in php) and return a result that the client code then uses to do something useful (or not do anything - that's possible just as well).

You seem to only have php code that's trying to call "ajax.php" ...

as to why you get the code, instead of it executing: file_get_contents read the content of a file ...

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php